# isset or !empty to determine if Wordpress array has content?

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress

I'm using the [ACF Gallery plugin](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/gallery/) for Wordpress that produces an array of image data.

It's called as so:

```
$floorplans = get_field('floorplans');
```

My problem is that sometimes, the array doesn't have any proper content e.g if i `var_dump()` it and they haven't uploaded any content, I get:

```
string(0) ""
```

If the result stored in `$floorplans` is empty, I want the script to skip over some statements.

I've tried:

```
if(!empty(get_field('floorplans'))){
...
}
```

... and yet the statements in my `if` still occur.

I tried:

```
if(isset(get_field('floorplans'))){
    ...
}
```

And I get:

> Fatal error: Cannot use isset() on the result of a function call

So then I tried:

```
$floorplanCount = count(get_field('floorplans'));
if ($floorplanCount !== 0){
...
}
```

And you guessed it, the statements in the `if` still pass.

So how can I not run a section of code if there is nothing in my `floorplans` field?

Comment: What do you get with `var_dump(get_field('floorplans'))`?

Comment: What version of PHP are you running? 5.3/5.4? [It works fine on 5.5+](https://3v4l.org/0tNst), but gets an error on 5.3-5.4. If you however set a variable first, and then use `!empty()` on that, [it will work in 5.3+](https://3v4l.org/3JSA4).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in comments `get_field` is the culprit, and a shining example of why a function shouldn't return multiple data types (array or string, array or int, etc), because it forces complexity on the calling code to have to figure out what was returned.

Try this:

```
if (((true === is_array($floorplans)) && (count($floorplans) > 0)) || (false === empty($floorplans))) {

    // Do work
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm marking this as correct because it gave some context and explanation too, though both answers were right,

Answer (score 1):

According to acf gallery documentation, you can use

```
          if($floorplans)
             {
               //your statements goes here
           }
```

Here is the link. http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/gallery/

The reason why you cant use isset is, the get_field function returns the array if anything exists, else it will return a false or 0 ( Im not sure, but even if it is 0 or false the $floorplan variable should work seamlessly in the if statement as I mentioned above )

Here is more documentation just in case : http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/get_field/

Comment: This is what I eluding too, the return value of `get_field` had to be returning a non-expected value for either of the use cases.

Comment: the get_field returns an array ( dimension depends on the type of the gallery ) or either a null/false/0 in case nothing matches the call.